# Modifying rand() ranges c++

Tags: c++, random, srand

I'm trying to make a guessing game program where the user thinks of a number between 1 and 100, and then the computer randomly generates(guesses) a number between 1 and 100. Then the user tells the computer if their number is higher(**H**), lower(**L**), or the same(**Y**) as the guessed number. The problem I am having is changing the range that the computer generates its guess in.

So let's say my number is **43** and the computer generates **15** as its guess. I would input **H**, indicating that my number is higher than its guess. The computer then changes the parameters to generate a number between **16** and **100**.

```
int high = 100, low = 1;
char answer;
```

Setting my variables.

```
srand(time(0));
```

I have this to truly randomize the generation.

```
int guess = rand() % high + low;
cout << "Is your number " << guess << "?\n";
cin >> answer;
```

Generate the number, ask if the number is what I'm thinking of, and then ask me to answer if it is higher, lower, or correct.

Then the segment that checks the answer and determines how to change the range of the randomly generated number.

```
switch (answer)
    {
    case 'H':
        low = (guess + 1);
        high = (high - guess);
        break;
    case 'L':
        high = guess;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

I guess what I'm not understanding is how rand() truly works. Like I understand the whole

```
rand() % 100 //range of 0 and 99
rand() % 100 + 1 // range of 1 and 100
```

But I want to know how I can change the parameters so that I get

```
rand() % max + min // range of min and max
```

while I constantly change and update the values for max and min.

Comment: Do you mean if `min = 3` and `max = 10` then you want a guess somewhere between 3 and 10? If so, then you would just do `rand() % (max + 1 - min) + min`.

Comment: If you can, use a better RNG such as [the ones built into C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) or [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_random.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically on the right track. Using `rand() % n` will give you a value in the half-open range [0, n). So if you want numbers from 0 to 100, inclusive, use `rand() % 101`. When you have a maximum and a minimum value, `n` is `max - min + 1`. That gives you a range of values starting at 0. To get a range of values that starts at `min`, just add `min` to the value.

Comment: The random numbers will not be distributed uniformly if the range of `rand()` is not a multiple of `n`.

Comment: @krlmlr - yes, that's what you said in your comment on the question.

Comment: You could do better with `rand()`, too. See http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html plus a few duplicate questions on this site.

Comment: @krlmlr - none of that is better. The only way to get rid of the non-uniformity is to discard some values. Rescaling just changes which values you get more frequently. But please, that's far enough down this rathole. If you have more to way, write your own answer.

Comment: Rejection sampling is mentioned in the FAQ I linked. ("When `N` is close to `RAND_MAX`...".)